# Total Number of Yearly Claims on top of bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

My code produces a barchart with subtotals within the bars before i introduce the second geom_text() to add the yearly totals on top.

```
yearly_totals <- df_claims %>%
  group_by(AccidentYear) %>%
  summarise(total = n())

gg_df_claims <- df_claims %>%
  ggplot(aes(AccidentYear, fill = bands2, color = bands2)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE), stat = "count") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = after_stat(count), y = after_stat(count)),
    stat = "count",
    position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE, vjust = 0.5),
    size = 2,
    color = "white"
  ) +
    geom_text(
    data = yearly_totals,
    aes(label = total, y = total),
    position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE, vjust = 0.5),
    size = 2,
    color = "black",  # Adjust the color for yearly totals
    fontface = "bold"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = v_greens, labels = labels2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = v_greens) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  ylab("Count of Claims") +
  theme_pubclean() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray", linetype = "dashed"),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank()
  )
```

Once I use the second geom_text() it no longer produces a graph and i get the error message.

```
Error in `geom_text()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error:
! object 'bands2' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The data are: df_claims

```
Schadenhöhe        bands2 AccidentYear
1     262000.0 Bis 1.000.000         2019
2       1000.0    Bis 50.000         2019
3      40000.0    Bis 50.000         2017
4       3000.0    Bis 50.000         2017
5      10000.0    Bis 50.000         2019
6       5000.0    Bis 50.000         2019
7      20000.0    Bis 50.000         2017
8      60000.0   Bis 250.000         2020
9       5000.0    Bis 50.000         2020
10     50000.0    Bis 50.000         2018
11     10000.0    Bis 50.000         2019
12     15000.0    Bis 50.000         2022
13      6000.0    Bis 50.000         2017
14     10000.0    Bis 50.000         2020
15     70000.0   Bis 250.000         2017
16      5000.0    Bis 50.000         2021
17      1000.0    Bis 50.000         2020
18     30000.0    Bis 50.000         2021
19    140000.0   Bis 250.000         2017
20      4000.0    Bis 50.000         2017
21      1000.0    Bis 50.000         2020
22     50000.0    Bis 50.000         2021
23     15000.0    Bis 50.000         2021
24     20000.0    Bis 50.000         2018
25      1000.0    Bis 50.000         2018
26      5000.0    Bis 50.000         2022
27     70000.0   Bis 250.000         2017
28     26416.1    Bis 50.000         2018
29      5000.0    Bis 50.000         2021
30     15000.0    Bis 50.000         2020
```

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: The second `geom_text()` inherits `fill = bands2` and `color = bands2` from `ggplot()`, but the data does not contain a variable `bands2`. Move `fill = bands2` into `geom_bar()` and `color = bands2` into the first `geom_text()`.

Comment: ... second option: Use `geom_text(geom_text(data = yearly_totals, aes(AccidentYear, total,  label = total), ..., inherit.aes=FALSE)` to not inherit the global aes.